# How do I extract data from a wxHaskell grid control?

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I've created a wxHaskell grid control, and it displays fine, the user can enter data etc.

It's also fairly obvious how to programatically write data into it ([`gridSetCellValue`](http://wxhaskell.sourceforge.net/doc/Graphics-UI-WXCore-WxcClassesAL.html#v%3agridSetCellValue)).

But how do I read the data from it? There's [`gridGetTable`](http://wxhaskell.sourceforge.net/doc/Graphics-UI-WXCore-WxcClassesAL.html#v%3agridGetTable) which might or might not be relevant, but that returns a [`GridTableBase`](http://wxhaskell.sourceforge.net/doc/Graphics-UI-WXCore-WxcClassTypes.html#t%3aGridTableBase) and while I can see that it's indirectly a pointer type, I can't find anything in the API to actually get at the data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data of a specific cell you can just use [`gridGetCellValue`](http://wxhaskell.sourceforge.net/doc/Graphics-UI-WXCore-WxcClassesAL.html#v%3agridGetCellValue), which is the obvious counter part to `gridSetCellValue`.